# Summing a large list of numbers is too slow

Tags: haskell, ghc

Task: "Sum the first 15,000,000 even numbers."

Haskell:

```
nats = [1..] :: [Int]
evens = filter even nats :: [Int]

MySum:: Int
MySum= sum $ take 15000000 evens
```

...but `MySum` takes ages. More precisely, about 10-20 times slower than C/C++.

Many times I've found, that a Haskell solution coded naturally is something like 10 times slower than C. I expected that GHC was a very neatly optimizing compiler and task such this don't seem that tough.

So, one would expect something like 1.5-2x slower than C. Where is the problem?

**Can this be solved better?**

This is the C code I'm comparing it with:

```
long long sum = 0;
int n = 0, i = 1;

for (;;) {

  if (i % 2 == 0) {
    sum += i;
    n++;
  }

  if (n == 15000000)
    break;

  i++;
}
```

**Edit 1**: I really know, that it can be computed in O(1). Please, resist.

**Edit 2**: I really know, that evens are `[2,4..]` but the function `even` could be something else `O(1)` and need to be implemented as a function.

Comment: I believe that my work on [http://www.joachim-breitner.de/publications/CallArity-TFP.pdf call arity] makes this much faster, by allowing `sum` to fuse, so one might try again with GHC 7.9 (the current git HEAD).

Answer (score 24, accepted):

## Lists are not loops

So don't be surprised if using lists as a loop replacement, you get slower code if the loop body is small.

```
nats = [1..] :: [Int]
evens = filter even nats :: [Int]

dumbSum :: Int
dumbSum = sum $ take 15000000 evens
```

`sum` is not a "good consumer", so GHC is not (yet) able to eliminate the intermediate lists completely.

If you compile with optimisations (and don't export `nat`), GHC is smart enough to fuse the `filter` with the enumeration,

```
Rec {
Main.main_go [Occ=LoopBreaker]
  :: GHC.Prim.Int# -> GHC.Prim.Int# -> [GHC.Types.Int]
[GblId, Arity=1, Caf=NoCafRefs, Str=DmdType L]
Main.main_go =
  \ (x_aV2 :: GHC.Prim.Int#) ->
    let {
      r_au7 :: GHC.Prim.Int# -> [GHC.Types.Int]
      [LclId, Str=DmdType]
      r_au7 =
        case x_aV2 of wild_Xl {
          __DEFAULT -> Main.main_go (GHC.Prim.+# wild_Xl 1);
          9223372036854775807 -> n_r1RR
        } } in
    case GHC.Prim.remInt# x_aV2 2 of _ {
      __DEFAULT -> r_au7;
      0 ->
        let {
          wild_atm :: GHC.Types.Int
          [LclId, Str=DmdType m]
          wild_atm = GHC.Types.I# x_aV2 } in
        let {
          lvl_s1Rp :: [GHC.Types.Int]
          [LclId]
          lvl_s1Rp =
            GHC.Types.:
              @ GHC.Types.Int wild_atm (GHC.Types.[] @ GHC.Types.Int) } in
        \ (m_aUL :: GHC.Prim.Int#) ->
          case GHC.Prim.<=# m_aUL 1 of _ {
            GHC.Types.False ->
              GHC.Types.: @ GHC.Types.Int wild_atm (r_au7 (GHC.Prim.-# m_aUL 1));
            GHC.Types.True -> lvl_s1Rp
          }
    }
end Rec }
```

but that's as far as GHC's fusion takes it. You are left with boxing `Int`s and constructing list cells. If you give it a loop, like you give it to the C compiler,

```
module Main where

import Data.Bits

main :: IO ()
main = print dumbSum

dumbSum :: Int
dumbSum = go 0 0 1
  where
    go :: Int -> Int -> Int -> Int
    go sm ct n
        | ct >= 15000000 = sm
        | n .&. 1 == 0   = go (sm + n) (ct+1) (n+1)
        | otherwise      = go sm ct (n+1)
```

you get the approximate relation of running times between the C and the Haskell version you expected.

This sort of algorithm is not what GHC has been taught to optimise well, there are bigger fish to fry elsewhere before the limited manpower is put into these optimisations.

Comment: Finally a clever answer! That point with exports is excellent among many.

Comment: How can we force GHC to produce version with unboxed ints?

Comment: By not having it construct an intermediate list. If you give it the above loop, it works with unboxed `Int#`s only. If you compile with `-fllvm`, you can even leave the `even n` instead of `n .&. 1 == 0` there (yet another low-level optimisation that there was not yet time to put in GHC). If something has to be put in a list anywhere, that something has to be boxed, so if you want unboxed, help GHC avoid lists.

Comment: @Martin, You've been told again and again in answers that lists aren't loops. Please take it on board.

Comment: I think Yatima2975 (below) has an important point about CAFs slowing things down and obscuring some of the issues. On my machine with ghc 8.0.2 and compiling with -O2 if I replace "evens" in mySum with "filter even [1..]" the code is about 30 times faster and sum seems to be a good consumer. If, after doing this, I compare mySum with the optimized dumbSum, then mySum is only 8 times slower than dumbSum. Some of this may also reflect that the ghc version I am using is about 5 years newer then the one used at the time of the original posts.

Comment: Thanks to Joachim's work, as he mentions above, sum is now a good consumer. Good to see GHC improving over the years! CAFs can still cause time and space performance issues though which is the point of my post a few minutes ago.

Answer (score 11):

The problem why list fusion can't work here is actually rather subtle. Say we define the right `RULE` to fuse the list away:

```
import GHC.Base
sum2 :: Num a => [a] -> a
sum2 = sum
{-# NOINLINE [1] sum2 #-}
{-# RULES "sum" forall (f :: forall b. (a->b->b)->b->b).
                sum2 (build f) = f (+) 0 #-}
```

(The short explanation is that we define `sum2` as an alias of `sum`, which we forbid GHC to inline early, so the `RULE` has a chance to fire before `sum2` gets eliminated. Then we look for `sum2` directly next to the list-builder `build` (see [definition](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/latest/doc/html/src/GHC-Base.html#build)) and replace it by direct arithmetic.)

This has mixed success, as it yields the following Core:

```
Main.$wgo =
  \ (w_s1T4 :: GHC.Prim.Int#) ->
    case GHC.Prim.remInt# w_s1T4 2 of _ {
      __DEFAULT ->
        case w_s1T4 of wild_Xg {
          __DEFAULT -> Main.$wgo (GHC.Prim.+# wild_Xg 1);
          15000000 -> 0
        };
      0 ->
        case w_s1T4 of wild_Xg {
          __DEFAULT ->
            case Main.$wgo (GHC.Prim.+# wild_Xg 1) of ww_s1T7 { __DEFAULT ->
            GHC.Prim.+# wild_Xg ww_s1T7
            };
          15000000 -> 15000000
        }
    }
```

Which is nice, completely fused code - with the sole problem that we have a call to `$wgo` in a non-tail-call position. This means that we aren't looking at a loop, but actually at a deeply recursive function, with predictable program results:

```
Stack space overflow: current size 8388608 bytes.
```

The root problem here is that the Prelude's list fusion can only fuse right folds, and computing the sum as a right fold directly causes the excessive stack consumption.
The obvious fix would be to use a fusion framework that can actually deal with left folds, such as Duncan's [stream-fusion package](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/stream-fusion), which actually implements `sum` fusion.

Another solution would be to hack around it - and implement the left fold using a right fold:

```
main = print $ foldr (\x c -> c . (+x)) id [2,4..15000000] 0
```

This actually produces close-to-perfect code with current versions of GHC. On the other hand, this is generally *not* a good idea as it relies on GHC being smart enough to eliminate the partially applied functions. Already adding a `filter` into the chain will break that particular optimization.

Answer (score 5):

Sum first 15,000,000 even numbers:

```
{-# LANGUAGE BangPatterns #-}

g :: Integer    -- 15000000*15000001 = 225000015000000
g = go 1 0 0
  where
    go i !a c  | c == 15000000 = a       
    go i !a c  | even i = go (i+1) (a+i) (c+1)
    go i !a c           = go (i+1) a c
```

ought to be the fastest.

Answer (score 4):

If you want to be sure to traverse the list only once, you can write the traversal explicitly:

```
nats = [1..] :: [Int]

requiredOfX :: Int -> Bool -- this way you can write a different requirement
requiredOfX x = even x

dumbSum :: Int
dumbSum = dumbSum' 0 0 nats
  where dumbSum' acc 15000000 _ = acc
        dumbSum' acc count (x:xs)
          | requiredOfX x = dumbSum' (acc + x) (count + 1) xs
          | otherwise     = dumbSum' acc (count + 1) xs
```

Comment: But then, if this should be the right solution, we could throw Haskell through the window and stay with `C`.

Comment: Most likely GHC optimizes the code in this way, but this way you have an objective comparison of your implementation. Also, I think even if we needed to write functions like this, there would be lots of compelling reasons to use Haskell.

Comment: @Martin Sure - if the only thing your program does is add up even numbers, it makes very little difference what language you write it in.

Comment: @Martin Wait.. you think haskell is worse than C because when you choose to not use recursion in haskell, you don't get the benefits of using recursion? When you choose not to use loops or bare recursion in C, how well does that go for you? How fast is your list based solution in C?

Comment: @AndrewC if I could award rep points for comments, I would, for that one. Seriously. :) *"How fast is your list based solution in C?"* This is T-shirts material. :)

Answer (score 3):

First, you can be clever as [young Gauss was](http://www.jimloy.com/algebra/gauss.htm) and compute the sum in *O(1)*.

Fun stuff aside, your Haskell solution uses lists. I'm quite sure your C/C++ solution doesn't. (Haskell lists are very easy to use so one is tempted to use them even in cases where it might not be appropriate.) Try benchmarking this:

```
sumBy2 :: Integer -> Integer
sumBy2 = f 0
  where
    f result n | n <= 1     = result
               | otherwise  = f (n + result) (n - 2)
```

Compile it using GHC with [`-O2` argument](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Performance/GHC#Use_optimisation). This function is [tail-recursive](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Tail_recursion) so compiler can implement it very efficiently.

**Update:** If you want it using `even` function, it's possible:

```
sumBy2 :: Integer -> Integer
sumBy2 = f 0
  where
    f result n | n <= 0     = result
               | even n     = f (n + result) (n - 1)
               | otherwise  = f result (n - 1)
```

You can also easily make the filtering function a parameter:

```
sumFilter :: (Integral a) => (a -> Bool) -> a -> a
sumFilter filtfn = f 0
  where
    f result n | n <= 0     = result
               | filtfn n   = f (n + result) (n - 1)
               | otherwise  = f result (n - 1)
```

Comment: Well, altough you've cheated and omitted the `even` function, that could be the answer. But it then means, that GHC is an idiot and cannot optimize even this simple scenario with `filter`.

Comment: @amindfv That's definitely true, but the optimizer is far from perfect.

Comment: @Martin Please post your C/C++ version so that we can compare.

Comment: @PetrPudlák Petře, je tam. Ale už na to kašli. Závěr je, že se to prostě napsat tou tail-rekurzí musí a že to současné GHC nezoptimalizuje. To je vše, co jsem chtěl vědět :-)

Comment: @Martin if ghc is an idiot because it can't optimise this simple code, who's the idiot for rejecting the best optimization - a better algorithm. You're aware of an O(1) algorithm. Use it. When you have a __genuine__ problem with haskell's speed, I'll be interested. Yet another rejection of good programming in favour of racing compilers pointlessly from you.

Comment: @Petr your last version is still not quite following the OP specs. You must use separate counter to count the successful numbers - we don't know where to start, for an arbitrary filtering function. But that's not important. :)

Answer (score 2):

Strict version works much faster:

```
foldl' (+) 0 $ take 15000000 [2, 4..]
```

Comment: No, unfortunately, it does NOT. At least on my machine.

Comment: [2,4...], no the `even` function is ALSO ESSENTIAL.

Comment: @Martin: It certainly should. How are you compiling your program?

Comment: Try it. `ghc -fllvm -optc-O2 -O2 foo.hs  -fforce-recomp`

Comment: @Martin: Give us your individual timings of the sum and the strict left fold versions, please.

Comment: @all Please... this answer is irrelevant, because the main SPEED-UP is because of the screwed-up form `[2,4..]`

Comment: @Martin: Are you telling us that you are not getting a speedup from using `foldl' (+) 0 . take 15000000 . filter even $ [1..]`? I find that very hard to believe, since the other version ought to be leaking memory everywhere.

Comment: @Sarah You're underestimating GHC. Since the type is given as `Int`, it makes the other version strict by itself, so there's no difference to `foldl' (+) 0`.

Comment: Yeah, GHC optimizations is smart :)

Answer (score 1):

Another thing to note is that `nats` and `evens` are so-called Constant Applicative Forms, or CAFs for short. Basically, those correspond to top-level definitions without any arguments. CAFs are a bit of an odd duck, for instance being the reason for the Dreaded Monomorphism Restriction; I'm not sure the language definition even *allows* CAFs to be inlined.

In my mental model of how Haskell executes, by the time `dumbSum` returns a value, `evens` will be evaluated to look something like `2:4: ... : 30000000 : <thunk>` and `nats` to `1:2: ... : 30000000 : <thunk>`, where the `<thunk>`s represent something that's not been looked at yet. If my understanding is correct, these allocations of `:` do have to happen and can't be optimized away.

So one way of speeding things up without altering your code too much would be to simply write:

```
dumbSum :: Int
dumbSum = sum . take 15000000 . filter even $ [1..]
```

or

```
dumbSum = sum $ take 15000000 evens where
    nats = [1..]
    evens = filter even nats
```

On my machine, compiled with `-O2`, that alone seems to result in a roughly 30% speedup.

I'm no GHC connaisseur (I've never even profiled a Haskell program!), so I could be wildly off the mark, though.

Comment: no, compiled with -O2, the OP code (plus `main = print dumbSum` definition) runs *standalone* in 1MB, but without it, it uses hundreds of MB. I take it to mean that with -O2 the lists aren't retained.

Comment: @WillNess: Fair enough, I didn't think to check the space usage. GHC is smarter than I thought it was, then! Thanks for the correction!