# Cartesian product "generator" (not list) in Haskell

Tags: performance, haskell, functional-programming, cartesian-product

I'm quite new to functional programming, and I'm trying to figure out a function that recursively generates elements of the cartesian product of a set of lists.

The functionality I'm looking for is exactly like `sequence` (as described here: [Calculate n-ary Cartesian Product](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3387359/calculate-n-ary-cartesian-product)), except that I don't want to express the whole thing as a list.
I'm currently using `sequence` and running into a variation of the problem described here: [Summing a large list of numbers is too slow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13399032/summing-a-large-list-of-numbers-is-too-slow).

As an example, `sequence [[1,2,3],[1,2,3]]` produces `[[1,1],[1,2],[1,3],[2,1],[2,2],[2,3],[3,1],[3,2],[3,3]]`. It's perfectly acceptable to deal with each combination (i.e. `[1,2]`, etc, as a list, I would just like to avoid building up the long outer list, instead processing the data recursively as it is calculated. How would I go about doing this?

I'm currently doing something similar to this  quick ghci exampl:

```
> let stuff = sequence $ replicate 10 [0..9]
> let morestuff = map (sum . take 2 . reverse . sort) stuff
> sum morestuff
```

and the last command is horribly, horribly slow.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "*processing the data recursively as it is calculated*"? That's exactly how lazy evaluation works in haskell.

Comment: the last command will force *each* combination to be calculated (and there are 10^10 of them) - I think you should concentrate on your algorithm instead of the evaluation details here first

Comment: for example: for each combination you only use the two largest numbers and just sum them up - so you don't need the cart. product at all (you just sort it again) ... just look for a way to generate them in an already sorted manner (and multiply the sum by the numbers of permuations after) ... I think it's really more a math problem (is this a project euler?) and I don't want to spoil to much as it's probably some contest ^^

Comment: btw: even if you have no clue as how to do it you could start by optimizing the `sum . take 2 .reverse . sort` stuff - see even if you only walk the list once and look for the two largest elements and sum them up you will save a lot

Comment: `sort` does not process the data as it is calculated. It needs all the data at once.

Comment: Try forcing the list between each `let` and you'll see that there's lots of time being spent in _all_ the phases -- laziness just means you only see it at the end unless you force earlier. One way to force things at the repl is to use `rnf` from `Control.DeepSeq`.

That said, you're generating and summing roughly 10^10 things, which is to say ten billion. So I wouldn't imagine that will go well regardless of how you write your code.

Comment: @Bergi, what I mean is not building up a list of all combinations.

Comment: Not part of any contest, just part of some stats and functional programming self study. Thanks for the comments so far. @Carsten, you're right this is basically a math problem - will continue to work on that aspect of it but any additional suggestsions would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: sclv, I just tried that and I see what you mean, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Moving my comment to an answer:

The only reason that the last line appears particularly slow is that it is forcing the work of all the other lines, which is otherwise accumulated lazily. So each sublist *is* being processed on an as-needed basis (though the sort on each forces the entire sublist).

To observe that all the phases take time and not just the last, we can use `rnf` from `Control.DeepSeq` on the intermediate results to force them as we go.

But generating and summing roughly ten billion things will take some time. As others have observed, this is a case where you should think more about a more clever way to get the result you want (i.e. what intermediate steps can be removed or transformed without changing the result, and what symmetries you can exploit) rather than just doing the brute force thing more efficiently.